# How to Initialize the value for the variable when runserver Django website thyon

Tags: python, django, dictionary, whoosh

I have a dictionary.txt file represented as {{key: value}}. I built a dictionary translation web so I wanted to initialize a variable whose data dictionary type is in python for storing. I use the django framework to process. Here is my dictionary reader.

```
def read_dictionary(fileName):
    dict = {}
    my_dict = {}
    with open(fileName, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
        for line in f:
            items = line.split(':')
            key, values = items[0].replace('X', '*'), items[1].strip().replace('\n', '')
            dict[key] = values
    for k, v in dict.items():
        my_dict.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
    return my_dict
```

How can I initialize variable my_dict = value from dictionary file and I can it in myapp folder ? Thank you. Do I need to create a model object and save it under the database?

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. You read the dict from a file an then ...?

Comment: then I use variable my_dict in myapp in django. But I doesn't work